# Is there a way of formatting strings in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Well , in python or java or ... we do sth like :  (the python version )

```
tmp = "how%s" %("isit")
```

and now tmp looks like "howisit".
 is there any bulit in thing like that in javascript ? ( rather than sprintf )

Thanks

Comment: you can use string replace with regex and match references: string replace - http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php ; regex - http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. Like string.replace(/(.)+(%s)/gi,'$1isit')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop, there isn't. You can do string concatenation.

```
var tmp = 'how' + 'isit';
```

Or `replace` in other situations. This is a stupid example but you get the idea:

```
var tmp = 'how{0}'.replace('{0}', 'isit');
```

Answer (score 2):

Not build in, but you can make your own templating by extending the String prototype:

```
String.prototype.template = String.prototype.template ||
   function(){
    var args = arguments;
    function replacer(a){
        return args[Number(a.slice(1))-1] || a;
    }
    return this.replace(/(\$)?\d+/gm,replacer)
   };
// usages
'How$1'.template('isit'); //=> Howisit
var greet = new Date('2012/08/08 08:00') < new Date 
             ? ['where','yesterday'] : ['are','today'];
'How $1 you $2?'.template(greet[0],greet[1]); // How where you yesterday?
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no string formating built in to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

No builtin function is there, however you can very easily build one yourself. The `replace` function can take a function argument and is the perfect solution for this work. Although be careful with large strings and complicated expressions as this might get slow quickly.

```
var formatString = function(str) {
    // get all the arguments after the first
    var replaceWith = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    // simple replacer based on String, Number
    str.replace(/%\w/g, function() {
        return replaceWith.shift();
    });
};

var newString = formatString("how %s %s?", "is", "it");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use these (simplistic) snippets;

```
function formatString(s, v) {
  var s = (''+ s), ms = s.match(/(%s)/g), m, i = 0;
  if (!ms) return s;
  while(m = ms.shift()) {
     s = s.replace(/(%s)/, v[i]);
     i++;
  }
  return s;
}

var s = formatString("How%s", ["isit"]);
```

Or;

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var s = (""+ this), ms = s.match(/(%s)/g) || [], m, v = arguments, i = 0;
    while(m = ms.shift()) {
        s = s.replace(/(%s)/, v[i++]);
    }
    return s;
}

var s = "id:%s, name:%s".format(1,"Kerem");
console.log(s);
```